# popup not displaying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I have added a Jquery pop-up in my code. When an edit button is clicked the popup will be opened with data which is kept inside an array 'editAccount'. It works on the first load, but after a few use, the data is not shown in the popup.

**INSIDE JS FILE**

```
/** View model in JS*/
function ClientViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.editAccount = ko.observableArray([]);
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

**HTML**

```
/** Method in HTML*/
 var clientViewModel = new ClientViewModel();
 clientViewModel.editAccount = function (item) {
            editSecItem = item;
            //console.log(item.ioru())
            var element = $('#accountDet')[0];
            ko.cleanNode(element);
            ko.applyBindings(item, element);
            dialog.dialog("open");

        } .bind(clientViewModel);
```

**POPUP**

```
    ko.applyBindings(clientViewModel, document.getElementById("clientDef"));
        dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 390,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                if (editSecItem.accountNumber() == "") {
                    clientViewModel.removeAccount(editSecItem);
                }
            }
        });
```

**POPUP HTML**

```
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Account">
        <table id="accountEdit" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         Account Number
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value:accountNumber">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <span class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons ok" onclick="dialog.dialog('close');">
                            <i></i>Done</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are any errors showing on the browser console?

Comment: no nothing is shown :(

Comment: try doing a console.log() before the line dialog.dialog("open"); ...it probably does not reach there the second time edit button is clicked?

Comment: I had already done it, in my case popup is displaying first, after a few seconds console is print